# How do I calculate the last day of any month in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, date

How do I correctly calculate the last day of every month in Javascript?

Follow below my thought process in code to calculate the last day of July 2021.

```
let tzoffset = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() * 60000;

//### Calculates the TIME at which today started
let todayStartedAt = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0) - tzoffset );
console.log('Today Started At: ' +todayStartedAt.toISOString());

//### Calculates the first day/date TWO months ago    
let twoMonthsAgo = todayStartedAt;
twoMonthsAgo.setMonth(todayStartedAt.getMonth() - 2);

twoMonthsAgo.setDate(twoMonthsAgo.getDate() - twoMonthsAgo.getDate() + 1 );
console.log('The first day 2 Months Ago was on: ' +twoMonthsAgo.toISOString());

var month = twoMonthsAgo.getMonth(); // July = 6
let year  = twoMonthsAgo.getFullYear(); // 2021

//### Calculates the LAST day/date TWO months ago 
var theLastDayTwoMonthsAgo = new Date(twoMonthsAgo.getFullYear(), twoMonthsAgo.getMonth() +1, 0);
console.log("The Last Day Two Months Ago was: " +theLastDayTwoMonthsAgo.toISOString() );
```

The code above yields:

```
Today Started At: 2021-09-09T00:00:00.000Z
The first day 2 Months Ago was on: 2021-07-01T00:00:00.000Z
The Last Day Two Months Ago was: 2021-07-30T21:00:00.000Z
```

Kindly NOTE that the results for `The Last Day Two Months Ago` is ERRONEOUS, as the last day in July does `NOT` end on the 30th of July, but rather the 31st of July.
Secondly, note that the time part of the date is: `T21:00:00.000Z` how do I alter this to read `T23:59:59.000Z`

Comment: `twoMonthsAgo.getDate() - twoMonthsAgo.getDate() + 1` is `1` btw.

Comment: `new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0) - tzoffset );` will return an incorrect result if it's called after the daylight saving change over time on the day of change. Anyway, `new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(0,0,0,0))` does the job in less code (though creating two Date objects rather than one is likely not performant and `let d = new Date(); d.setUTCHours(0,0,0,0)` is less code). :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `setDate()` with value of 0 (Zero).

Example:

```
let august=new Date(2021,7,1); //Take first day of august, to find last day of July
august.setDate(0); // This is now the last day of July
```

> For example, if 0 is provided for dayValue, the date will be set to the last day of the previous month.

From here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.